# Splitting a table cell and using automatic spacings

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, automation

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
Things & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \\ 
Things & Word $\quad\quad\quad\quad\  \,$  \parbox[t]{0.75\linewidth}{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}  \\ 
 & Anotherword   $\quad$ \parbox[t]{0.75\linewidth}{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

There are 3 issues with this MWE:

- In this MWE I adjusted the spacing right of `Things B` by hand. This I want to avoid. First, I want to avoid having to manually find (by trial and error) and specify the length of `parbox`, which in this case was `0.75`.
- Second, I want to avoid having to manually define a spacing between the `Word` and the Lorem Ipsum this word in my table will summarize and the `Anotherword` and that Lorem Ipsum that word will summarize. Here I did that by finding enough many `\quad`s etc. that did that, but I want to avoid doing that by hand.
- Thirdly, there is a twist to the last bullet. One might be tempted to define a table with one more column to achieve that and then use `\multicoliumn` for the upper row (or some similar solution). This does not work for me as this MWE is part of a much bigger table, which has already a fixed number of columns and I really would like to avoid having to change any code there. (Maybe I can nest a table inside the cell right of `Things B` to achieve this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If this had to be table, see if this solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}      % added
\usepackage{calc}          % added

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
Things  & 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.       \\
Things &  % use of description list
        \begin{description}[font=\normalfont, nosep,
                            leftmargin=!,
                            labelsep=2\tabcolsep, 
                            labelwidth=\widthof{Anotherword}, 
                            before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}]
        \item[Word]         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        \item[Anotherword]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        \end{description}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and without of `table` and `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}      % added
\usepackage{calc}          % added

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, nosep,
                    leftmargin=!,
                    labelsep=2\tabcolsep,
                    labelwidth=\widthof{Things}]
\item[Things]   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.       \\
\item[Things]   
        \begin{description}[font=\normalfont, nosep,
                            leftmargin=!,
                            labelsep=2\tabcolsep,
                            labelwidth=\widthof{Anotherword}]
    \item[Word]         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \item[Anotherword]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.